# Autohotkey - Remap mouse wheel when mouse touch edge of screen

Tags: autohotkey

I want to remap mouse wheel down to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> but only when the mouse touches the right edge of the screen. I know how to remap the mouse wheel scroll but i don't know how to make it work only when the mouse touch the edge of the screen:

`WheelDown::^!e`

I hope someone can help me with the rest of the script.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this, if you mean touching the right edge, it means that the `X` coordinate of the mouse is equal the *maximum* usually, the screen's width (±1 pixel).

- `#If` can be used to create context-sensitive hotkeys. See [#If](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/_If.htm)
- `A_ScreenWidth` can be used to get the screen's width. See [A_ScreenWidth](http://ahkscript.org/docs/Variables.htm#Screen)
- `CoordMode` can set coordinates mode to be relative to the whole screen. See [CoordMode](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/CoordMode.htm)
- `MouseGetPos` gets the current mouse coordinates. See [MouseGetPos](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/MouseGetPos.htm)

Please take the time to analyse this example.

## Example script

```
#If MouseIsTouchScreenRight()
WheelDown::^!e
#If

MouseIsTouchScreenRight() {
    CoordMode, Mouse, Screen ;set coordinates mode to be relative to the whole screen
    MouseGetPos, mX ;store the X coordinate of the mouse in `mX`
    if ( abs(A_ScreenWidth-mX) <= 2 ) ;if the "absolute" difference is within 2 pixels
        return true
    return false
}
```